# Designing a specific home network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I'm about to redesign my home network and due to a two meter (six foot) thick load-bearing wall running straight through, I need some assistance in what kind of configuration I need to make it work.

First of all, I'd like to mention that I've tried a bunch of repeaters / extenders to make my WiFi work in the rooms behind the wall, but to no avail. That's why, for this iteration, I've decided to go with access points instead of repeaters.

**Prerequisites**

- I have an Ethernet connection in the wall (fiber) in one far corner of my apartment, where I'll put modem / router.
- The thick stone wall running through my apartment has prevented the WiFi signal from reaching two rooms, regardless of tested meshing solutions.
- Due to the above, I've decided to use two access points, one for each room behind the wall.

**The actual questions**

1. Do I need both a modem and a router?
2. I have both wired and non-wired equipment, and I intend to use access points - do I need a switch?

Comment: Thanks for your input, Tim! I live in Sweden, the ISP is Tele2 and the speed is 100/100 Mbit over fibre. I may increase the speed in the future as well, and I am willing to spend a bit more to make sure the setup can handle it.

Comment: How do they hand off the connection? Do you need a modem/router from tele2. I was trying to find out from Google, I couldn't find much other than a certain percentage of people there have a fiber connection from the local municipal. But didn't find much in the way of how it's actually delivered. Is it on strand or two in your home?

Comment: I should also point out, that there is a stack exchange community for hardware recommendations. This community is more for hardware/software troubleshooting. We deal with building or fixing configurations etc. I would ask for the recommendation for hardware there, and ask for help in the network setup/build/config here. Best regards!

Comment: Great input again! :) I'm not sure about how it's delivered, but we do get a modem sent to us as we sign the service, typically included. There's no lock to their specific equipment though, I can connect whatever stuff I need. All I see is a TP outlet in the wall. Also, afaik, all fiber is delivered by the local municipal; there're no privately owned ground cables in Sweden. I'll make sure to check out the other communities as well, for future questions! Good catch!

Comment: Well, them essentially giving you a fiber to Ethernet converter, that makes your network equipment selection that much easier. And much less expensive on your budget.

Comment: Aah, great! Well, the products I'm expecting to purchase then are (all Ubiquiti), a Security Gateway USG, a Cloud Key Controller, two AP Light and an 8 port 60W switch (specifically, the PoE ports for the APs). Would you say that's a good setup? The AP's will be on each side of the wall.

Comment: Even if you are not ready for it yet, I would suggest 802.1q (vlan) capable equipment.

Answer (score 1):

For Access points you still need a router so that it provides NAT, Network Address translation, in other words - to hand out local IP addresses. You dont need a switch though.

You can find a router that has fibre input or socket for one and get rid of modem, unless its used for something else, like cable TV in addition to internet connection.

I highly suggest using Mikrotik equipment, those are ISP grade, but have friendly web based configuration tools too.

The setup would be having 3 of these: MikroTik RB962UiGS-5HacT2HnT, one in router mode connected with fibre card through FX port, and 2 in AP mode connected with the first one via regular LAN cable (or Wifi, if you like).

Comment: Errr, NAT has nothing to do with handing out IP addresses. That's a DHCP server. I should also point out, you just gave a shopping recommendation without knowing what type of service is lighting the fiber port. Is it single strand to the house like Verizon FiOS here in the states? Is it metro Ethernet which is full duplex over two strands? It could be a proprietary service? What speed is it? Without knowing this, it's not really a good idea to tell someone who clearly needs help, recommendations for a service you have no clue about, speed, ISP service etc. ask for clarification from the OP.

Comment: It's what the comment section is for.